# Incremental Instrumented Android Test Results

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, teamcity

I am using TeamCity and I am looking at how to get incremental instrumented android test results.

To run the tests I run ./gradlew :TestApp:connectedAndroidDebugTest --info

This gives me output of what tests are running and their state but the full report is only generated at the end.

How can I get incremental android test results in TeamCity?  I can add custom logs that TeamCity will pick up, but I am unsure where to add them in the gradle build file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, you are using `Command Line` runner step.

Try using `Gradle` runner step instead. You will get on-the-fly test reporting with it. TeamCity will display each test as soon as it is executed.

Comment: I have it setup to use the gradle runner and the task it runs is :TestApp:connectedAndroidDebugTest with the additional  parameter is --info. In the build log I can see what tests have passed, but on the project home it just shows the current step (:TestApp:connectedAndroidDebugTest) with a spinning progress pie.  I was expecting to see progress on that line and a test tab with the incremental results.

Comment: I see. Please report the issue here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=TW